# How to display text in the browser status bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, statusbar

How can we change the text displayed in the browser status bar  using JavaScript (or jQuery)?

Comment: Don't do it.  User has to allow it, anyways.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

jQuery is not necessary to do this:

```
<script>
function writetostatus(input){
    window.status=input
    return true
}
</script>
```

However, most newer browsers prevent you from setting the text in the status bar from JavaScript.

Comment: but will not work in Firefox by default - https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.status

Comment: Most newer browsers prevent you from setting the text in the status bar from JavaScript

Comment: @Chris - I'm betting the next question is likely to be how to do something like this cross-browser :)

Comment: @Russ Cam,no,I'm gonna ask why SO gave up highlight the whole area of accepted answer?

Comment: I understand that public websites abused this feature, but many intRAnet apps depended on it, and are now either broken, or require help-desk staff to visit thousands of desktops to manually turn it on. Browser vendors should have left it on by default for intranet domains/scope. The blunt removal was not thought through, and this arrogance makes me angry: don't break standards without a public hearing on the tradeoffs! Arrrg!

Answer (score 34):

**This can be done**.  Google Search is doing it, which can be seen when you hover over a Google link, the status bar shows the underlying site:

[image]

Yet when you click it, it brings you to a location and user-agent dependent url that looks like [`https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAAahUKEwi4lP-Z4_rIAhVLk5QKHXRLAe8&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFEbIRqDC65KFpmuak0aXKmnzjKVQ&bvm=bv.106923889,d.dGo`](https://www.google.com.sg/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CC8QFjAAahUKEwi4lP-Z4_rIAhVLk5QKHXRLAe8&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2F&usg=AFQjCNFEbIRqDC65KFpmuak0aXKmnzjKVQ&bvm=bv.106923889,d.dGo). The url does Google tracking and whatnot before redirecting you to `https://www.example.com`. You can easily test this using Network Inspector with "[preserve log](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12282621/632951)".

They're using a *hacky hack* but it works **across all browsers**.

The trick is to realize that we can set the status bar to almost anything using only HTLM's `a href` (no CSS nor JavaScript needed). All we need is to trick the browser's parser into thinking that the `href` value is a valid url and it will display it.

Try running this snippet:

```html
<a href="http://.# this is p͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜͜‌​̴̵̶͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔͕͓͔̖͕͓̖̱̲̳̖̖̖̖̖̖̖͕̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̒̓̔̐̕̚͜͜͜͜͜‌​͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚̕̚͜͜͜͜͜‌​͕͓͔̖͕͓͔̖̐̑̓̑̒̓̔̐̑̓̓̓̓̓̓̓̑̒̓̔̕̚̕̚͜͜owerful because ━Σ(ﾟДﾟ|||)━ symbols !@)(*#&$^%</even htlm> or lorem ipsum in all scripts Лорем ипсум Lorem存有 ငါ့ရဲ့ဇာတ်မြင့် घरՏուն Дома ലോറെൻ  ഇപ്സം درமுகப்புЛорем ипсумలోלורם איפסוםరెం ఇప్సమ్ მთავარი હોમ לורם איפסוםלורם איפסום Forsíða Loremのイプサム ಮುಖಪುಟ ទំព័រដើម 가 lorem ipsum의 ຫນ້າທໍາອິດ Տուն আর্কাইভ">Hover this link (do not click) and observe the browser's status bar.</a>
```

Chrome's output (click image to maximize): (v46.0.2490.80 m)

[image]

FireFox's output: (v42.0)

[image]

IE's output: (v11.0.9600.17905 Update Versions 11.0.21 (KB3065822))

[image]

Opera's output: (v33.0.1990.58 stable)

[image]

Seamonkey's output: (v2.38)

[image]

Avant's output: (v Ultimate 2015 build 28)

- IE 11 engine:

  [image]
- IE compatible engine:

  [image]
- Chrome engine:

  [image]
- FireFox engine:

  [image]

Torch's output: (v42.0.0.10546)

[image]

Baidu's output: (v43.19.1000.119)

[image]

Maxthon's output: (v4.4.8.1000)

[image]

---

Also, it's not necessary to use `#` (the [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier)). Browsers will consider a text like  `http://some.message.here./and_more_message_here` as a valid url too. Weirder strings might be considered valid depending on the browser:

1. ``` <a href="http://a.b.c.d/test_symbols_!#$%^&*()[]{};:'&quot;.><,//=+``~"> ```

   (Chrome, FireFox, IE, SM, Torch, Baidu, Maxthon, Avant IE11, Avant IE Compat, Avant Chrome, Avant Firefox.)

   (Names are listed for browsers with expected output, names are striked ("<s>example</s>") for browsers with no status bar output, and names are underlined ("e̲x̲a̲m̲p̲l̲e̲") for browsers with unexpected output/behavior. Tested with browser versions same as the ones listed above.)
2. `<a href="http://a.b.c.d/test some spaces">`

   (Chrome, FireFox, I̲E̲, SM, Torch, B̲a̲i̲d̲u̲, M̲a̲x̲t̲h̲o̲n̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲1̲1̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲C̲o̲m̲p̲a̲t̲, Avant Chrome, Avant Firefox.)
3. `<a href="http://test some . spaces in domain part/a_b_c_d_e">`

   (C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲, <s>FireFox</s>, I̲E̲, <s>SM</s>, T̲o̲r̲c̲h̲, B̲a̲i̲d̲u̲, M̲a̲x̲t̲h̲o̲n̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲1̲1̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲C̲o̲m̲p̲a̲t̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲, <s>Avant Firefox</s>)
4. `<a href="http://test some . spaces in domain part without slash">`

   (C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲, <s>FireFox</s>, I̲E̲, <s>SM</s>, T̲o̲r̲c̲h̲, B̲a̲i̲d̲u̲, M̲a̲x̲t̲h̲o̲n̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲1̲1̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲C̲o̲m̲p̲a̲t̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲, <s>Avant Firefox</s>)
5. `<a href="http://test_without_slash_and_dots">`

   (Chrome, FireFox, IE, SM, Torch, Baidu, Maxthon, Avant IE11, Avant IE Compat, Avant Chrome, Avant Firefox)
6. `<a href="http://a.b.c:port_with_letters_test">`

   (<s>Chrome</s>, <s>FireFox</s>, <s>IE</s>, <s>SM</s>, <s>Torch</s>, <s>Baidu</s>, <s>Maxthon</s>, <s>Avant IE11</s>, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲C̲o̲m̲p̲a̲t̲, <s>Avant Chrome</s>, <s>Avant Firefox</s>)
7. `<a href="http://http://double.http.test">`

   (Chrome, FireFox, IE, SM, Torch, Baidu, Maxthon, Avant IE11, Avant IE Compat, Avant Chrome, Avant Firefox)
8. `<a href="http://test @ with spaces">`

   (C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲, <s>FireFox</s>, <s>IE</s>, <s>SM</s>, T̲o̲r̲c̲h̲, B̲a̲i̲d̲u̲, M̲a̲x̲t̲h̲o̲n̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲1̲1̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲C̲o̲m̲p̲a̲t̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲, <s>Avant Firefox</s>)
9. `<a href="http://test:password@ with spaces/">`

   (C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲, <s>FireFox</s>, <s>IE</s>, <s>SM</s>, T̲o̲r̲c̲h̲, B̲a̲i̲d̲u̲, M̲a̲x̲t̲h̲o̲n̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲1̲1̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲C̲o̲m̲p̲a̲t̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲, <s>Avant Firefox</s>)
10. `<a href="http:// test : password @with.spaces/">`

    (C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲, FireFox, <s>IE</s>, SM, T̲o̲r̲c̲h̲, B̲a̲i̲d̲u̲, M̲a̲x̲t̲h̲o̲n̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲1̲1̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲C̲o̲m̲p̲a̲t̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲, Avant Firefox)
11. `<a href="http://test@double@a.b.c.d">`

    (C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲, FireFox, <s>IE</s>, SM, T̲o̲r̲c̲h̲, B̲a̲i̲d̲u̲, Maxthon, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲1̲1̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ I̲E̲ ̲C̲o̲m̲p̲a̲t̲, A̲v̲a̲n̲t̲ C̲h̲r̲o̲m̲e̲, Avant Firefox)
12. Repeat all of the test strings above, with `http://` replaced by `https://`, `ftp://`, `about://`, `chrome://`, `file://`, `foobar://`, and etc.

We can see that if the browser doesn't consider the string to be a valid url, it will fail gracefully by displaying no status bar, so no harm done. (Except that it looks like there's some  bugs going on for Avant IE Compat with the test string `"http://a.b.c:port_with_letters_test"`.)

---

Getting the browser status bar to display our desired string is only the first step. The second step is to stop the browser from loading the page when the user clicks the link.

This can easily be done using `return false`:

```html
<a onclick="return false" href="http://some.message.here./and_more_message_here">this link will not load</a>
```

or:

```html
<a onclick="return f()" href="http://some.message.here./and_more_message_here">this link will not load</a>
<script>
  function f() {
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Above two snippets are tested to work on Chrome, FireFox, IE, SM, Torch, Baidu, Maxthon, Avant IE11, Avant IE Compat, Avant Chrome, Avant Firefox.

---

The last step is to use [`window.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location) or [`window.open`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) to mimic the behavior of `a href`. It can be done inline: ([online test](https://googledrive.com/host/0B53jM4a9X2fqYWhoOUFhaHg3WGM/Snippet%201))

```
<!doctype html>
<a onclick="location='http://example.org'; return false" href="https://some.message.here./and_more_message_here">same tab</a>
<br><a onclick="window.open('http://example.org'); return false" href="https://some.message.here./and_more_message_here">new tab</a>
```

Or using `return func()`: ([online test](https://googledrive.com/host/0B53jM4a9X2fqYWhoOUFhaHg3WGM/Snippet%202))

```
<!doctype html>
<a onclick="return f1()" href="http://some.message.here./and_more_message_here">same tab 2</a>
<br><a onclick="return f2()" href="http://some.message.here./and_more_message_here">new tab 2</a>
<script>
  function f1() {
    location = 'http://example.org';
    return false;
  }

  function f2() {
    open('http://example.org');
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Or inline with `setTimeout`: ([online test](https://googledrive.com/host/0B53jM4a9X2fqYWhoOUFhaHg3WGM/Snippet%203))

```
<!doctype html>
<a onclick="setTimeout(function(){location='http://example.org';},1); return false" href="https://some.message.here./and_more_message_here">same tab 3</a>
<br><a onclick="setTimeout(function(){window.open('http://example.org');},1); return false" href="http://some.message.here./and_more_message_here">new tab 3 (doesn't work on Avant IE11 and Avant IE Compat if this link is HTTP; works if it is HTTPS or FTP)</a>
```

Or using `return func()` with `setTimeout`: ([online test](https://googledrive.com/host/0B53jM4a9X2fqYWhoOUFhaHg3WGM/Snippet%204))

```
<!doctype html>
<a onclick="return f1()" href="http://some.message.here./and_more_message_here">same tab 4</a>
<br><a onclick="return f2()" href="http://some.message.here./and_more_message_here">new tab 4 (doesn't work on Avant IE11 and Avant IE Compat if this link is HTTP; works if it is HTTPS or FTP)</a> <!-- hadn't tested this with sourcepage=HTTP. only tested with sourcepage=HTTPS and sourcepage=localwebpage -->
<script>
  function f1() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      location = 'http://example.org';
    }, 1);
    return false;
  }

  function f2() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      open('http://example.org');
    }, 1);
    return false;
  }
</script>
```

Above two snippets are also tested to work on Chrome, FireFox, IE, SM, Torch, Baidu, Maxthon, Avant IE11 (with caveat stated in the code), Avant IE Compat (with caveat stated in the code), Avant Chrome, Avant Firefox.

Comment: Then you can focus the anchor and display updated data continuously https://jsfiddle.net/4rfsx0qL/

Answer (score 3):

To whom it may concern a simple note **specific to IE**:

**Until IE6 and including it** you could do:

```
window.status = "Hello, I'm a custom status bar note.";
```

**But after IE6 (tested IE7/8)** you do it in the same way, but **you need also to adapt the browser security options** by turning the feature on: Tools - Internet Options - Security - Custom Level:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, its appearence is not uniform throughout browsers, and secondly, that functionality [has been disabled](http://blog.taragana.com/index.php/archive/how-to-enable-windowstatus-in-firefox/) for a long time [by default](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/webkit-dev/2008-February/003353.html) on most browsers for security reasons.

Anyway, the javascript for doing that is a simple `window.status = "my text"`

Answer (score 0):

An answer to 10 yrs old question.If the idea was to hide where links lead to.
I use this function

```
<script>
    function go2(hell){ window.location=hell; }
</script>

and the links will be like this :
<a href="#" onclick="go2('www.somewhere.net/page.html')">my link</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

use

`window.status = "whatever you want"`