# How To Show Final Redirected Url In Browser Bottom When Hover

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I found different ways to hide real url when we hover links, but did not found a way to show real and final url in browser bottom when we hover links, when a url have a redirect. Is there any way to do that like javascript, php, or any advance css i don't know. I know the final url but don't know how to show it when we hover links. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I think you're referring to the status bar. You can't set a value in this (anymore), see e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444770/how-to-display-information-at-the-status-bar-of-browser

Comment: not statusbar, its browser bottom popup when we hover links